# Simple inequation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

for some values $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{n-1} \in \left[-1, 1\right] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and a constant $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\delta \geq 0$ the following properties hold:

$
1 \geq \underbrace{\lvert\lambda_1\rvert \geq \lvert\lambda_2\rvert \geq \ldots \geq \lvert\lambda_q\rvert}_{\lvert\lambda_i\rvert > \delta\lvert\lambda_1\rvert} \geq \underbrace{\lvert\lambda_{q+1}\rvert \geq \ldots \geq \lvert\lambda_{n-1}\rvert}_{\lvert\lambda_i\rvert \leq \delta\lvert\lambda_1\rvert}
$

I'm trying to prove the following inequation:

$
\lvert\frac{\lambda_{q+1} + \ldots + \lambda_{n-1}}{\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_{n-1}}\rvert \leq \delta
$

I've filled sheets of paper trying to prove this, but nothing seems to work out. I think I'm really overlooking the elephant in the room here. Can you help?

EDIT: I often get stuck trying to relate $q$ and $\delta$. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.  Take $n$ very large, $q$ rather small, $\delta=\frac 12, \lambda_1=1, \lambda_2 \dots \lambda_q=\frac 12+\epsilon, \lambda_{q+1}\dots \lambda_{n-1}=\frac 12-\epsilon$  Then $$\lvert\frac{\lambda_{q+1} + \ldots + \lambda_{n-1}}{\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_{n-1}}\rvert \approx \frac {\lambda_1\delta (n-q-1)}{\lambda_1n\delta}=\frac {n-q-1}n\approx 1 \not\leq \delta$$